# need a help for modify .htaccess rule

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

here is my wp `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

now I want combine the below rules into my wp `.htaccess`. `new` is a new page which I created in the wp admin panel and set the hyperlink make the URL looks like `http://localhost/wordpress/new`

```
# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
##Options All -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
##Options +FollowSymLinks

# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /new

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Rewrite current-style URLs of the form 'new?url=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I have easily add  `# Rewrite current-style URLs of the form 'new?url=x'.` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new?url=$1 [L,QSA]` in wp `.htaccess`, not work, even bronken all the links in wordpress. So how to do in right way?